# How to save files' names containing spaces to an array in bash?

Tags: bash, ls

Let's say that there are 3 files in a directory: `file1`, `file 2`, `file    3`.
I must use `ls` to get the file names and save them to an array. The problem is that, for example, bash sees the name `file 2` as two separate elements: `file` and `2`, while `file1` is properly interpreted.

I understand that bash uses spaces as separators of array elements.
Is it possible to change the separator temporally in the script to double quotes for example?
It would solve the problem 'cause in that case it would simply be the matter of using ls with -Q option.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). If this is a homework assignment, find a new teacher / lecturer.

Comment: I'd just do something like `array=(file*)`

Comment: @Shawn those are just examples. The files' naming in the end will not be schematic. Must work for any file name.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you for the link. Hadn't found it during my research. At this point I think I'll just give up. I'm working on a laboratory assignment for which a simplified version of a file explorer for linux terminal must be created using bash and dialog.

Comment: @Nicolas So change the wildcard pattern to whatever's appropriate.

Comment: @Shawn There is no pattern.

Comment: There's always a pattern. Even if it's just `*`.

Comment: Useful references: [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), and ["Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly"](https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).